# Doctrine2 what is the best way to update entities? ( Database => Doctrine )

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have all my entities set and I have my repositories linked in annotations like this:

```
/**
* User
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User
{....}
```

now I go to my sql database and add a new column or any other change. I need to update doctrine model and at the moment I do it like this :

1 ) `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import App\\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity`

2) `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App`

these commands are purging my entities annotations and I get:

```
/**
* User
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User
{....}
```

3) I have to relink all my repositories manually in each entities (I have 12)

QUESTION:
Is there a way to update `from database to entity` while keeping all repository links at the top of my entities? How do you do it ?

I could not find anything in the doctrine manual; I was hoping for a `doctrine:mapping:import` setting ?

Comment: please check this documentation regarding ["Database first" pattern by Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/getting-started-database.html#getting-started-database-first)

Comment: as well please read this official Symfony documentation reg Doctrine ["Reverse Engineering"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going from database to entity, go by another way: from entity to database

1. add needed property to the entity. like

```php
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $name;
```

2. run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` you will get migration with changes like `$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user ADD name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL');`
3. run migration

---

**EDIT**

If you still want to go by your way, at least you could narrow down changes only to one entity by adding `--filter="user"` to both your commands

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this is way more work than just adding 12 repo in my case as I do frequent multiple changes. I would like to keep it `database to entity`

Comment: Denis' way is the way to go. The 'database to entity' approach is more or less only there to set up an entity model based on an existing database. from there on you should go 'entity to database'. otherwise you contradict the ORM approach (e.g. database indepency etc.)

Comment: @LBA I understand what you are saying. But what if I prefer to edit my DB in a dedicated software like Sequel Pro ? Is there absolutely no way to do do what I am asking for ? As far as I am concerned, both ways are valid; it is just a workflow preference.

Comment: @Sam: I have a different opinion on this. If you use ORM you design the entity model and not the database - I understand your approach, but to my knowledge it's simply not designed this way.

Comment: @Denis Thanks for the edit, I think it is a good alternative. I will accept the answer if it turns out `DB to ORM` way is in fact impossible

Comment: I’ll add another vote for the entity to db workflow, which also adds a lot of built in optimization’s like indices and foreign keys automatically that you are unlikely to fully reproduce on your own.